# Adding sum of a dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba, sum, range

New to stack here.

I'm on VBA and am creating a quoting tool where outputs are generated if certain cells are populated from row 57 onwards. I.e. "For a = 57 to 1000".

For each of row "a" that has values, I'm trying to have Cells(a + 1, 6) output the sum of the previous a columns.

It took some time to find how to reference a range using cells, but I've been stuck from there. To reference the range I've found something along the lines of below

```
With Sheet1
    .Range(.Cells(a, 6), .Cells(a + 1, 6)).Value2 = "b"
End With
```

The `.Range(.Cells(a, 7), .Cells(a + 1, 7))` are the cells that I want to create a sum for but I'm not sure how to do this (and whether the `With Sheet1` and `End With` sections are needed.

[image: Screenshot]

Full VBA code here:

```
Sub OnEntry()

On Error Resume Next
    
    For a = 14 To 1000
        If IsEmpty(Cells(a, 3)) = False And IsEmpty(Cells(a, 4)) = True Then
            
            If IsEmpty(Cells(a + 2, 4)) = True And IsEmpty(Cells(a + 3, 4)) = True And IsEmpty(Cells(a + 2, 3)) = True Then
                GoTo GoHere
            End If
            
            If IsEmpty(Cells(a, 4)) = True And IsEmpty(Cells(a + 1, 4)) = False Then
                GoTo GoHere
            End If
            
            Find = Range("'Sheet1'!$B$6:$B$5000").Find(Cells(a, 3).Value).Address
            Row# = Range(Find).Row
    
            Cells(a, 4) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row#, 3)
            Cells(a, 5).Value = "=VLOOKUP(C" & a & ", 'Sheet1'!$B$6:$F$5000, 4, 0)"
            Cells(a, 7).Value = "=B" & a & "*E" & a

   
            If Cells(a - 1, 1) = "Line" Then
                Cells(a, 1).Value = 1
            Else
               Cells(a, 1).Value = Cells(a - 1, 1) + 1
            End If
            
            Cells(a + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
            
            **Stuck here**
            With Sheet2
             .Range(.Cells(a + 1, 7), .Cells(a + 2, 7)).Value2 = "b"
            End With
            
            
            
        End If
        
    Next a
    
GoHere:
    
    WaitTime = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    While Now() < WaitTime
        DoEvents
    Wend  
End Sub
```

Comment: First remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line is evil. It hides **all** error messages, but the errors still occur, you just cannot see their messages. If you don't see your errors you cannot fix them if you don't fix them your code does not work. So remove that line and fix your errors (or tell which errors you get and where).

Comment: If you just need a sum of a known range, its `WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(a, 6), Sheet1.Cells(a + 1, 6)).Value)`

Comment: Thank you.

@Toddleson have changed it to;

`Cells(a + 1, 6).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(a, 6), Sheet2.Cells(a - 1, 6)))`

It gives the sum of the last two values, which is progress. But what would the sum be to add all the lines (i.e. more than 2)? Thanks again

Comment: Instead of  `a - 1` you would do `a - x` where `x` is the number of lines. You would find `x` by doing a while loop like `While Cells(a + x, 6).Value <> "": x = x + 1: Wend`